# Replace data in a column using R

Tags: r

I have a column in my data frame with data something like below:

```
RIsGreat
ILoveDataAnalysis
...
...
```

The labels are getting very long when plotting it using ggplot. Tried using str_wrap but that doesnt help because these are one-word labels.

Tried to replace `RIsGreat` with `R Is Great` using `replace(x, "RIsGreat", "R Is Great)`. This doesn't work.

Can anyone please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `gsub("([A-Z][a-z]*)","\\1 ",Events)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(snakecase)
library(dplyr)
Events <- c("RIsGreat", "ILoveDataAnalysis")

to_mixed_case(Events) %>% gsub("_"," ",.)
```

Comment: There's also a new `snakecase::to_title_case()` now. In addition to parsing and separating by spaces it also uses case conversion similar to `toos::toTitleCase()` (which it's wrapping especially for this purpose): `> snakecase::to_title_case(Events)` gives `[1] "R is Great"           "I Love Data Analysis"`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex that just inserts space between letter (any case) followed by capital letter. If you have other edge cases, can modify.

```r
Events <- c("RIsGreat", "ILoveDataAnalysis")
gsub("([A-z])([A-Z])", "\\1 \\2", Events)
#> [1] "R Is Great"           "I Love Data Analysis"
```

Created on 2018-05-01 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Does that work for single letter words, though? For example, `"ILoveDataAnalysis"`. Does it parse the `I` and `Love` correctly?

Comment: Nope! it returns `ILove Data Analysis`. Working on resolving this.

Comment: `gsub("([[:alpha:]])([[:upper:]])", "\\1 \\2", x)` solves this problem @Lyngbakr :)

Comment: `gsub("([A-Z][a-z]*)","\\1 ",Events)`